# Upload image on form in Express-Handlebars

Tags: html, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I want to upload image in a form using Express-Hnadlebars. here is my form (made it simpler, I have other `text` types)

```html
  <form action="{{{postRoute}}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%; margin: 0; cursor: pointer;">افزودن تصویر
                <input name="image" onchange="readURL(this);" type="file" style="opacity: 0; position: absolute;">
            </label>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 30px; width: 50%;">ایجاد
                اعلان</button>

        </form>
```

and In my express function , I log the req.body but its an empty object.

If I **remove the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`  it works and `req.body` has valus for my input** with the texts and the file is just filename (which is useless .. isn't it?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for uploading image using express you will need a  middleware for handling multipart/form-data you can try this one : https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer